# What are spurious local optima?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I keep seeing that word "spurious" (when used in the context of optimization), but I'm having trouble finding a good reference on what the definition of the term is.

Comment: Can you provide some context of the places you keep seeing it in?

Comment: google does it. (i searched for "spurious local".) that phrase really seems to be pretty common.

Comment: OK, those always seem to explain the term as soon as they bring it up -- local optima that are not the global optimum.

Answer (score 1):

according to the abstract here:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11222-014-9455-3

**(non-interesting) local optima or singularities**